# How can i read .xls files (Excel) with PHP?

Tags: php, excel, xls

I need to convert an .xls file to text, i dont need it formatted in any way.
The file is filled with productids like PN-5098P, which i will preg_match_all to get.

What is the simplest solution?
I tried simply opening the file in a regular texteditor, the ids are not showing, so i guess i need some kind of binary converter?

Comment: .xls files are for all intents and purposes binary garbage. You'll need a proper excel parsing library to handle this. Attempting to write one yourself will just lead to insanity, lack of hair, and eventual suicide.

Comment: "Microsoft Excel up until 2007 version used a proprietary binary file format called Binary Interchange File Format (BIFF) as its primary format" // "The default Excel 2007 workbook format. In reality a ZIP compressed archive with a directory structure of XML text documents."

Answer (score 6):

XLS is a complex proprietary format, and it might be difficult to work with. If you end up having trouble with libraries like [Clint suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128616/how-can-i-read-xls-files-excel-with-php/8128645#8128645), consider only accepting files in a more simpler format, like CSV, which is super-duper easy to deal with. If that solution is acceptable in this situation, it'll end up making your life much easier.

Answer (score 6):

Newer versions of MS Office can output your spreadsheet directly in XML format.  Here's an example of using such an XML-format spreadsheet directly from PHP:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/

Otherwise, I've heard good things about PHPExcel:

- http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Here's one other link that might at least give you some additional ideas:

- http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dataexport/

Answer (score 1):

I convert my Excel sheets to MySQL using <strike>xls2mysql.com</strike>, but it isn't perfect. It doesn't recognize characters like -, /, é, ü, ô etc.. I've been working around this by converting those characters to a number in between hash tags (#4# for -) and unconverting them afterwards, but it is a bit of a hassle.