# php read data from xls or html and show in php page

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have program that can export customer in Guest.xls or Reservations.html 
[here is picture of sample excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5nCs.png)

here is sample xls and html
[http://upload.i4th.in.th/th/download.php?id=56C57BA61][http://upload.i4th.in.th/th/download.php?id=56C57BA61]

if i want to php click import file then it read the data then
show checkbox for all customer list.
afterthat i can select which customer from checkbox to update in database.

i try and no idea how to read it. really newbie for php .

thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all you might want to reconcinder the approach you are taking here. Reading a XLS file is difficult because it is a specific type for a specific program and not an overall accepted file format for data like .csv .xml and json which are very easy to work with in PHP.

If you want to still continue working with PHP and xls files here is a good start:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-excel-reader/

Taken from: [How can i read .xls files (Excel) with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128616/how-can-i-read-xls-files-excel-with-php)

Comment: hi latrick. the app also can export in html. but i dont know how to read data from html that software can export also. do u have any idea.

Comment: html you can parse and read with javascript, but still that will cause overhead. What you need to understand about XLS files is that is in default a .csv file but with added data for excel. If you can export to XLS it is a simple job to convert XLS to csv. There are lot of converters free to use on the internet. Try find a command line tool and run it as background task? Lots of oppertunities